# For Python Pandas, how to implement a "running" check of 2 rows against the previous 2 rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[updated with expected outcome]

I'm trying to implement a "running" check where I need the sum and mean of two rows to be more than the previous 2 rows.

Referring to the dataframe (copied into spreadsheet) below, I'm trying code out a function where if the mean of those two orange cells is more than the blue cells, the function will return true for row 8, under a new column called 'Cond11'. The dataframe here is historical, so all rows are available.

Note that that Rows column is added in the spreadsheet, easier for me to reference the rows here.

[image]

I have been using .rolling to refer to the current row + whatever number of rows to refer to, or using shift(1) to refer to the previous row.

```
df.loc[:, ('Cond9')] = df.n.rolling(4).mean() >= 30
df.loc[:, ('Cond10')] = df.a > df.a.shift(1)
```

**I'm stuck here... how to I do this 2 rows vs the previous 2 rows? Please advise!**

**The 2nd part of this question:** I have another function that checks the latest rows in the dataframe for the same condition above. This function is meant to be used in real-time, when new data is streaming into the dataframe and the function is supposed to check the latest rows only.

Can I check if the following code works to detect the same conditions above?

```
cond11 = candles.n[-2:-1].sum() > candles.n[-4:-3].sum()
```

Comment: Kindly provide sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: Hi Sammy, the spreadsheet is actually what I copied over from the dataframe output from python. Added the Cond11 column in the spreadsheet for the expected outout. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solves your problem:

```py
df.rolling(4).apply(lambda rows: rows[0] + rows[1] < rows[2] + rows[3])
```

The first 3 rows will be `NaN`s but you did not define what you would like to happen there.

As for the second part, to be able to produce this condition live for new data you just have to prepend the last 3 rows of your current data and then apply the same process to it:

```py
pd.concat([df[-3:], df])
```